# Multiple IP addresses and Host Names used by Spark Driver and Master

Tags: apache-spark

Spark Master listens on several ports. Unfortunately the IP address / hostname scheme used differs among them - and it often happens that connections failed.

Then we are left to wonder: how to fix the connection problems:  Spark decides on its own how to translate among:

- hostname
- hostname.local  (on mac os/x)
- hostname.domain
- localhost
- localhost.localdomain
- 127.0.0.1
- external IP address
- internal ip address (on AWS)

The important consideration:  some of the networking clients/connections need an **exact string match**  to successfully contact the master. So in that case `127.0.0.1` is not the same as `hostname`.  I have seen in cases where `hostname` works and `hostname.local` does not: that one is a Mac-centric problem. But .. then the former stops working - and I lack the tools to troubleshoot why.

The `--master` provides opportunities for confusion on the Linux when you have an internal and external IP address.

Below is an example on my Mac.  I see other patterns on AWS and yet other ones on standalone clusters.  It is all perplexing and time consuming since it is not clearly documented either:

- where the mappings occur
- how to achieve a consistent master address string across:

  - master
  - master web ui
  - akka address for master

Below we see output when the `--master` option were provided to spark-submit.

```
--master spark://mellyrn:7077
```

Notice the variety of ip addresses

```
http://25.x.x.x:4040
akka.tcp://sparkMaster@mellyrn:7077
mellyrn/127.0.0.1:707
```

Here is the output on MAC:

```
15/07/31 12:21:34 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
15/07/31 12:21:34 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
15/07/31 12:21:34 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://25.101.19.24:4040
15/07/31 12:21:34 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master akka.tcp://sparkMaster@mellyrn:7077/user/Master...
15/07/31 12:21:35 WARN AppClient$ClientActor: Could not connect to akka.tcp://sparkMaster@mellyrn:7077: akka.remote.InvalidAssociation: Invalid address: akka.tcp://sparkMaster@mellyrn:7077
15/07/31 12:21:35 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@mellyrn:7077]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: Connection refused: mellyrn/127.0.0.1:7077
15/07/31 12:21:54 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master akka.tcp://sparkMaster@mellyrn:7077/user/Master...
15/07/31 12:21:54 WARN AppClient$ClientActor: Could not connect to akka.tcp://sparkMaster@mellyrn:7077: akka.remote.InvalidAssociation: Invalid address: akka.tcp://sparkMaster@mellyrn:7077
15/07/31 12:21:54 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@mellyrn:7077]. Address is now gated for 5000
```

On Linux the spark connection with --master option **does** work (though .setMaster() does not reliably).  Yet even on linux there is a variety of master/driver strings generated:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was discovered: Spark is binding to a different local interface.  I had a VPN client on the 25.X.X.X address - but the hostname pings to 10.X.X.  **This is a likely bug in spark**.  I will look into if a JIRA were already submitted for it.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same problem recently. It always prompt as 
"Exception: could not open socket"  when I use "collect".

But it worked fine when my vpn is connected.  I was trying to unify all the name of the node